# Git branch doesn't exist or doesn't have permissions after creating

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I created a branch, and ran the following:

```
git push [branchname]
```

I got:

```
fatal: The current branch [branchname] has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

git push --set-upstream [branchname] [branchname]
```

Then I ran:

```
git push --set-upstream [branchname] [branchname]
```

I got:

```
fatal: [branchname] does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

How can I solve this? I prefer to have a terminal solution, thanks!

Comment: Did Git generate that suggestion?
I think the correct command should be `git push --set-upstream [remotename] [branchname]`. At least for me, when I do this, I get the suggestion `git push --set-upstream origin tmp`, when trying to push a `tmp` branch which has no defined upstream.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, this is what I got now:
fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
  asked for: [remotename]
   redirect: [remotename asking for a login]
But whats weird about that, I can pull and push from other branches, so I dont know why it's asking for a login

Comment: Do you have more than one remote? The first remote is almost always named `origin`; a second one, if you have it, is commonly named `upstream`. Note that a remote is essentially shorthand for a URL. If most of your branches go to `origin` (at one web site) but one goes to `upstream` (at a different web site), it's not surprising that one would behave differently. The actual names for these "remotes" (origin, upstream, etc) are up to *you*. The default `origin` one is so common because it's the default that `git clone` makes if you don't choose a different one.

Comment: @torek I dont think I have many more remotes, i made one for thi push too, but it kind of loops into the same, with url etc it still suggests me to:

fatal: The current branch [branchname] has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream [remotename] [branchname]

Comment: The command `git remote` (with no other arguments) will list all your remotes. The syntax for `git push` is, as Alderath already said, `git push [options] <remote> <branchname>`, not `git push <branchname> <branchname>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your local branch seems it don't have a upstream. First, find out your remote tracked repositories using

```
git remote -v
```

most time you will get

```
origin git@xxx (fetch)
origin git@xxx (push)
```

It means you have a remote named `origin`. So you can push your local branch to remote using

```
git push origin <local_branch_name>
```